# How to recognize adjectives in speech?

Tags: c#, .net, kinect

For a project, I would like to have people talk in front of a Kinect (v1) and every adjective they say should appear on a screen.
Unfortunately, I'm new to Kinect development and I'm having real trouble finding good documentation and tutorials.

I did some testing of the idea, but the best I could do is hack one of the Kinect SDK samples for basic speech recognition and put some adjectives in the grammar.
The problem is that this doesn't work well when saying full sentences in front of the Kinect, and you have to speak pretty loudly and close to the Kinect. I will not be able to place the Kinect that close to the speaker.

I've also tried using `System.Speech` and (like the sample) `Microsoft.Speech`. However, none of them seem to support the `Dictation` grammar. I did some research on what the error (`Grammar referenced by grammar not found`) means, and it seems this indicates that the dictating functionality is not installed on my system, or something similar. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Can you point me to some other things I could try to recognize the adjectives people are saying in front of a Kinect (or another microphone)?

Comment: Questions ask for off-site resources are **off-topic** for StackOverflow.

Comment: Where could I ask this question, then? Or how do I improve it?

Comment: You can use the free [HUnspell](http://www.crawler-lib.net/nhunspell) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the grammar-based speech recognition which I simply prefilled with a lot of adjectives. Users were limited to saying one word at a time, instead of being able to speak freely, but I couldn't make it work otherwise.